# What happened when I used pandas to read csv files for multiple time in kaggle's notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, kaggle

I am participating the kaggle's [NCAA March Madness Anlytics](https://www.kaggle.com/c/march-madness-analytics-2020) Competion. I used pandas to read the information from csv files but encountered such a problem:

```
seeds = pd.read_csv('/kaggle/input/march-madness-analytics-2020/2020DataFiles/2020DataFiles/2020-Womens-Data/WDataFiles_Stage1/WNCAATourneySeeds.csv')
seeds
```

Here the output is empty. And I tried again like this:

```
rank = seeds.merge(teams)
```

Then there came an error:
NameError: name 'seeds' is not defined.

I can't figure out what happened and I tried it offline which turned out that nothing happened. Do I miss anything? And how can I fix it? Note that this was not the first time I used the read_csv() to read data from csv file in this notebook, though I couldn't figure out whether there is relation between this trouble and my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. I didn't notice I was writing my codes in the markdown cell. Stupid me!

Answer (score 1):

You must put the CSV file in the folder where python saves projects.
Run this to find out the destination:

```
%pwd
```

Put the file in the destination and run this:

```
seeds = pd.read_csv('WNCAATourneySeeds.csv')
```

You can also run this:

```
seeds = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users....\WNCAATourneySeeds.csv')
```

Where "C" is the disk where your file is saved and replace "..." by the computer path where the file is saved. Use also "\" not "/".